# Sql trigger to start and pass parameters to windows service

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, windows-services, sqldependency, triggers

I have a working windows service that generates reports based on parameters. I need to start a windows service when a new row inserted into a table and pass some newly inserted values to service to generate report. How to accomplish this? Am pretty new to this so please elaborate answer!

Comment: Whatever the trigger does ought to be *fast* and *local* - you shouldn't try any form of (direct) communication outside of the same database that contains the table the trigger is applied to. You might want to look at e.g. service broker as a means of (eventually) notifying some other piece of code of some interesting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `xp_cmdshell`, then you could run a `NET START` command, but usually `xp_cmdshell` is not a good idea to allow for a user as they'll need the `sysadmin` role.

Comment: ...am pretty new to this can you please elaborate what you suggested? is it possible to write a trigger directly?how ? I have done reading and implementing job agents but didnt work..

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx - Create Trigger documentation